# XamlParseException in WPF application - but only on when installed on XP

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-xp, xamlparseexception

My WPF application is running fine on Windows 7. Installation on XP machine brings up the following error on startup:

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was
>   terminated due to an unhandled
>   exception.
>
> Exception Info:
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
>
> Stack:    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception,
>   System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader,
>   System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory,
>   Boolean, System.Object,
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings,
>   System.Uri)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader,
>   Boolean, System.Object,
>   System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel,
>   System.Uri)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext,
>   System.Object, Boolean)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object,
>   System.Uri)
>
> at
>   MyApplication.App.InitializeComponent()
>
> at MyApplication.App.Main()

I think I may be experiencing the problem described in the answer to this question:

[XamlParseException on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481178/xamlparseexception-on-windows-xp)

as I am using PresentationFramework.Aero in places. Is there a way to fix this or will I have to remove Aero? This is a pain as I am using some ButtonChromes

TIA

Comment: i am having the exact same problem, have you found a solution that you can post an answer to your question?

Answer (score 6):

I had  the  same problem on Windows XP SP3 and for me the problem was solved by setting the **"Copy Local"** property of the PresentationFramework.Aero reference to **"True"**.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to the ResourceDictionary for Aero, try specifying the full assembly name, not the short assembly name.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure there are no exceptions being thrown in the constructors for any of the UI 
  components (such as codebehind for .cs files).
- Make sure if you're using MVVM that you're not throwing any exceptions in the ViewModel constructor.

I had a view model throwing an exception (related to a COM component [which I'm now going to go track down!]) that had NOTHING to do with Xaml at all. You'll get a `XamlParseException` if the creation of a Xaml based component fails - and it can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

FIX: An exception in the XAML parser is thrown when you run a WPF application on a computer that has customized English (United States) regional settings.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968227

Comment: the original link is rotten, read it here:  http://web.archive.org/web/20120623034740/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968227