# WPF : XamlParseException in WPF application when installed on XP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-xp, xamlparseexception

I have a WPF application which runs perfectly fine on vista/7 but on Windows XP it chucks up the System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse error.

I use Visual studio 2010 with .NET 4.0, Telerik Q2 2011 Controls and DevExpress Control 2011.

Detail about exception:

```
Application: CVServer.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception,    System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at Procesta.CvServer.App.Main()
```

Update 1:

I am applying styling from a static resource file

Update 2:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="Background" GradientOrigin="-0.01,1.01" RadiusY="0.52">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF62BAFB"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF0070DA" Offset="0.479"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF00499F" Offset="1"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>
<FontFamily x:Key="ButtonFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBlockForeground" Color="Black"/>
<System:Double x:Key="ButtonFontSize">13.333</System:Double>
<System:Double x:Key="TextFontSize">14.667</System:Double>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD0D8E8" Offset="0.006"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E9F1" Offset="0.124"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="0.972"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ImageButtonForeground" Color="Black"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ImageButtonToolTipBorder" Color="#FFA30909"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ImageButtonToolTipBackground" Color="#A18C8C93"/>
<System:Double x:Key="ImageButtonFontSize">16</System:Double>
<FontFamily x:Key="ImageButtonFontFamily">Adobe Kaiti Std R</FontFamily>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Apply those Resource like this

```
Background="{DynamicResource Background}"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046177/xamlparseexception-in-wpf-application-but-only-on-when-installed-on-xp (set PresentationFramework.Aero to copy local)

Comment: Xaml code? Repro it to what tag causes it. Also - is there an inner exception? You get a rewrap exception but dont show the original which is likely the inner exceptio nof the XamlParseException.

Comment: Can you paste the ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries where you are applying the styling?

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem can be the usage of Segoe UI Font. This font is not installed with XP.

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ButtonFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
```

Comment: I solve my problem. it occurs for Background="{DynamicResource Background}". i change put some Static-resource.Thank all